# How to maintain session in Jmeter for testing web application?

Tags: jmeter

How to maintain session in Jmeter so that each user should login, search tickets and then logout ? and this process kept going until loop completes for all users.
As I am trying to test our web application with multiple users.

Comment: show us code you've tried?

Comment: As Jon wrote, show us your approach. But probably the 'standard' way is just to prepare login -> requests - > logout list and feed it with logins and passwords from csv or other source.

Answer (score 1):

Each JMeter Thread (representing a virtual user) executes samplers upside down so if you have 3 samplers for login, search and logout each thread will execute them in that order.

Keep in mind that:

1. You need to provide different credentials to each thread so they could impersonate different users. The most common way of parametrization is using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. It's better to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to represent browser cookies.
3. It may also be required to perform correlation: in majority of cases application expects dynamic parameters which need to be extracted from previous page response and added to the next request. If you fail to do it you may not even be logged in. The most commonly used test element for correlation is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) however depending on the nature of the response it may worth be using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor), [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/)

Answer (score 1):

Add Cookie manager. Afterwards it depends on the application you will need dynamic values like viewState or eventValidation or similar ones. But first add the manager and get to the next problem :)